# determine if object is in a set of a models foreign key?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

This is my models.py:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    actualBlog = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class BlogComments(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    actualBlog = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I passed a list of all the existing blogs to my template. In my template, I want to see if request.user is in the list of users who have commented on the blog. Something like this:

```
{% for blog in allExistingBlogs %}
    {% if request.user in blog.blogcomments_set.all %}
        <p>you have already commented on this blog</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>you have not commented on this blog yet</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

but that doesn't work. I also tried

```
    {% if request.user in blog.blogcomments_set.all.user %}
```

but that doesn't work either. Any idea on how to get it to work?

Comment: Have you tried using a template tag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorate the object in your view, before you send it to your template:

```
def show_blogs(request):
    all_blogs = Blog.objects.all()
    blogs = []
    for blog in all_blogs:
       blogs.append((blog, blog.blogcomments_set.all(),
                           blog.blogcomments_set.filter(user=request.user).count()))
    return render(request, 'blogs.html', {'blogs': blogs})
```

Now, in your template:

```
{% for blog, comments, commented in blogs %}
   {{ blog }} - {{ comments.count }}
   {% if commented %}
       You have already commented!
   {% else %}
       Would you like to comment?
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Good answer. By the way, Why exactly did you add .count() at the end of 'blog.blogcomments_set.filter(user=request.user).count()'? Because with the .count() there, then {% if commented %} will always return true because an empty list still exists. So I removed the .count so that {% if commented %} will now return false if the user has not commented on it yet.

Comment: @user2719875 `count()` returns an integer, 0 if there are no comments, so `{% if commented %}` evaluates to `False`. The documentation recommends using [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) instead of boolean evaluation of a queryset, if that is all you need, because it's more efficient (but not much).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a model method in `Blog`:

```
def _get_commenters(self):
    commenters = self.blogcomments_set.values_list(user, flat=True)
    return commenters
commenters = property(_get_commenters)
```

Then you just use that in the template:

```
{% if request.user in blog.commenters %}
```